# Showing the difference of an unbounded sequence and a convergent sequence is unbounded

Tags: real-analysis

In the problem I am working on the author wants me to show an example, or a case given various theorems that an example is impossible for the following problem:

> An unbounded sequence $(a_n)$ and a convergent sequence $(b_n)$ with $(a_n - b_n)$ unbounded.

After some work trying to find an example, I figured this is likely not possible. I set off to prove it. Writing down what I know:

1. A convergent sequence is bounded

I tried to prove it and ended up getting no where. I had attempted to show that $|a_n| \le M$ and we know $|b_n - b| \lt \epsilon$, but this ended up getting me no where either. The author's proof was elegant, but I am not sure how he can make such a conclusion so quickly:

> Such a request is impossible. By Theorem 2.3.2 $(b_n)$ is bounded. If $(a_n - b_n)$ were bounded we could show that $(a_n) = (a_n - b_n) + (b_n)$ would also have to be bounded, which is not the case. So this is unbounded.

I am not sure how he jumped to the conclusion he did. Is there a rule I am missing? How can he conclude that in general $(a_n - b_n) + (b_n)$ could not happen given $(a_n)$ being unbounded and $(b_n)$ being convergent? In this section we didn't discuss the results of combining these types of sequences. Is there some place I can read more about these properties?

Comment: An example is $a_n = n$, $b_n = 1$. Then $(a_n)$ is unbounded, $b_n$ is convergent to $1$ and the difference sequence $a_n - b_n =n-1$ is unbounded. So there *is* an example. The argument shows that given $a_n$ and $b_n$ as stated, $a_n - b_n$ will **always** be unbounded.

Comment: Oh, I see. Since $a_n$ is unbounded no matter what we do to it, we will always remain unbounded since eventually the $b_n$ will hit its bound and $a_n$ will eventually exceed it?

Comment: yes, something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(d_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are bounded sequences. Then there are numbers $M$ and $N$ such that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\lvert c_n\rvert<M\text{ and }\lvert d_n\rvert<N.$$But then$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\lvert c_n+d_n\rvert\leqslant\lvert c_n\rvert+\lvert d_n\rvert<M+N.$$That is, the sequence $(c_n+d_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded.

Comment: So the key here is to show that assuming that $a_n$ is bounded leads to a contradiction that would indicate their difference is bounded and so therefore it is impossible?

Comment: Almost. What you assume here is that $(a_n-b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is unbounded.

Comment: Is there a property of some kind that proves the sum of bounded sequences is bounded? Or is this a conclusion directly from the fact convergent sequences are bounded? I am hung up here - mostly because I don't want to use anything that appears _obvious_ without a theorem/proof to back it up.

Comment: My answer contains that proof.